# How can I hide channels from YouTube?

Tags: youtube, ads

Some highly ranked YouTube channels seem to do nothing but reupload others' videos and slap advertisements on them. I am really, really tired of giving those channels views, but it's sometimes hard not to. I'm looking for a browser plugin of sorts to help me in this.

For example, say you want to view the TF2 "Meet the Spy" video; [the official video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OR4N5OhcY9s) isn't even on the search results page, while the top hit comes from the Machinima channel. One has ads, the other doesn't; guess which?

For bonus points, in addition to removing videos from known bad channels, it would be nice if I got a warning before loading a video of theirs through a direct link. For example, today I was linked to Gamespot's reupload (full of the lamest advertisements ever seen in the history of the *world*) of [the official video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnXfrlXPMOI) announcing Toki Tori 2. A warning would've been nice.

Is there anything like this out there?

I'm happy to view ads to support content creators and refrain from using ad blockers whenever possible, but I don't want to give sharks my impressions.

Comment: Sorry about that.  If it makes you feel any better when **I** watched it, it was the official video.  I just went back to find one to link in the chat.

Comment: No worries @GnomeSlice; not your fault. The search feature is what's really to blame.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of is a greasemonkey script to hide the video when username is equal to whatever expression you want, however the page would have been loaded so technically the uploader would stick get a click through link.

Answer (score 1):

Youtube doesn't have any option to hide all videos from a specific Youtube user/channel. You can use this user script on Chrome or Firefox: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/156278

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but you may be able to block the channel. *I have not tested this to see if it does in fact totally remove seeing them from the searches.*

Comment: I have, and it doesn't work :(